# HttpClient retrieve all headers

Tags: c#, http, http-headers, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

Currently, I am working on API wrapper. If I send a bad `Consumer Key`, the server will return `Status` as `403 Forbidden` in the header. It will also pass custom headers. How do I actually retrieve these custom headers?

This is the response receive from the server.

```
Cache-Control: private
Date: Wed,  01 May 2013 14:36:17 GMT
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml",  CP="ALL CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND UNI COM NAV INT STA PRE"
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Amazon)
Status: 403 Forbidden
X-Error: Invalid consumer key.
X-Error-Code: 152
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.20
Connection: keep-alive
```

I need to retrieve the `X-Error` and `X-Error-Code`. Currently, I am using `HttpClient` class to process the request. If I watch the headers respond under Quick Watch in VS Studio 2012, I could find it like this

`((System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders)(response.Headers)).headerStore["X-Error-Code"].ParsedValue`

Is there any other way to do this?

Edit:
`headerStore` is not accessible thru code as this is private field. I only get access to it through the Quick Watch window.

This is my snippet for the request:

```
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("/v3/oauth/request", content);
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Well, [`HttpResponseMessage.Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.headers.aspx) returns an [`HttpResponseHeaders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpresponseheaders.aspx) reference, so you should be able to use [`GetValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.getvalues.aspx)

```
string error = response.Headers.GetValues("X-Error").FirstOrDefault();
string errorCode = response.Headers.GetValues("X-Error-Code").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Nope, I can't do that as I would receive this error `Error 3Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpResponseHeaders'`. I'll update my code above for clarity.

Comment: @ShulhiSapli: Ah - hadn't spotted that it was `HttpClient`. Will edit.

Comment: If you requires more detail, you can take a look here, https://github.com/shulhi/PocketNet/blob/dev/PocketNet/PocketNet/Authenticator/PocketOauth.cs

Answer (score 44):

Since the title of the question is "retrieve all headers", I wanted to add an answer in regards to that.

The [`HttpResponseMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.aspx) returned by `HttpClient` methods has two header properties:

- `HttpResponseMessage.Headers` is an [`HttpResponseHeaders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpresponseheaders.aspx) with generic response headers
- `HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers` is an [`HttpContentHeaders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.aspx) with content-specific headers like `Content-Type`

Both objects implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>`, so you can easily combine all the headers with something like this:

```
var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
var headers = responseMessage.Headers.Concat(responseMessage.Content.Headers);

// headers has type IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,IEnumerable<String>>>
```

The reason it's an-enumerable-set-of-names-with-multiple-values is because **some** HTTP headers (like `Set-Cookie`) can be repeated in a response (even though the majority of other headers can only appear once - but software should gracefully handle an RFC-violating webserver returning invalid headers).

### Generating a `string` of all headers:

We can generate a flat string of headers using a single Linq expression:

- Use `Concat` to combine both `HttpResponseMessage.Headers` and `HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers`.

  - Don't use `Union` because that won't preserve all headers.
  - (As a personal style preference, when I'm concatenating two `IEnumerable<T>` objects together, I start off with `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` for visually symmetrical results - not for performance or any other reason).
- Use `.SelectMany` on each Headers collection to flatten each collection *before* concatenating their flat results.
- Use `Aggregate` with a `StringBuilder` to efficiently generate a `string` representation.

Like so:

```
    HttpResponseMessage resp = await httpClient.GetAsync( url );

    String allHeaders = Enumerable
        .Empty<(String name, String value)>()
        // Add the main Response headers as a flat list of value-tuples with potentially duplicate `name` values:
        .Concat(
            resp.Headers
                .SelectMany( kvp => kvp.Value
                    .Select( v => ( name: kvp.Key, value: v ) )
                )
        )
         // Concat with the content-specific headers as a flat list of value-tuples with potentially duplicate `name` values:
        .Concat(
            resp.Content.Headers
                .SelectMany( kvp => kvp.Value
                    .Select( v => ( name: kvp.Key, value: v ) )
                )
        )
        // Render to a string:
        .Aggregate(
            seed: new StringBuilder(),
            func: ( sb, pair ) => sb.Append( pair.name ).Append( ": " ).Append( pair.value ).AppendLine(),
            resultSelector: sb => sb.ToString()
        );
```

### Loading all headers into a `NameValueCollection`:

Another alternative is to use the classic `NameValueCollection` class from .NET Framework 1.1, which supports keys with multiple values (indeed, it's used in Classic ASP.NET WebForms for this purpose):

Like so:

```
    HttpResponseMessage resp = await httpClient.GetAsync( url );

    NameValueCollection allHeaders = Enumerable
        .Empty<(String name, String value)>()
        // Add the main Response headers as a flat list of value-tuples with potentially duplicate `name` values:
        .Concat(
            resp.Headers
                .SelectMany( kvp => kvp.Value
                    .Select( v => ( name: kvp.Key, value: v ) )
                )
        )
         // Concat with the content-specific headers as a flat list of value-tuples with potentially duplicate `name` values:
        .Concat(
            resp.Content.Headers
                .SelectMany( kvp => kvp.Value
                    .Select( v => ( name: kvp.Key, value: v ) )
                )
        )
        .Aggregate(
            seed: new NameValueCollection(),
            func: ( nvc, pair ) => { nvc.Add( pair.name, pair.value ); return nvc; },
            resultSelector: nvc => nvc
        );
```

Comment: This creates a very complicated type for the headers variable.  How do get the data out to a string or a simple collection?

Comment: @JamieMarshall Since it puts everything into an IEnumerable of key/value pairs you should be able to use a foreach loop to go through the combined list. The key of each pair is the header name, and the value of each pair is the list of header values.

Comment: It's worth noting that for the `Concat` to work you need to make sure you include `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 14):

Just a gotcha that I found when attempting to find a header that didn't exist. You should use TryGetValues instead of GetValues because at runtime it will throw an exception if the header is not found. You would use something like this code:

```
IEnumerable<string> cookieHeader; 
response.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out cookieHeader);
```

Answer (score 6):

A bit bulky, but simple to understand..

```
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("----- CLIENT HEADERS -----" + Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> myHeader in myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(myHeader.Key + Environment.NewLine);
                foreach(string myValue in myHeader.Value)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("\t" + myValue + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("----- MESSAGE HEADERS -----" + Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> myHeader in myHttpRequestMessage.Headers)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(myHeader.Key + Environment.NewLine);
                foreach (string myValue in myHeader.Value)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("\t" + myValue + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("----- CONTENT HEADERS -----" + Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> myHeader in myHttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(myHeader.Key + Environment.NewLine);
                foreach (string myValue in myHeader.Value)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("\t" + myValue + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
(String[])response.Headers.GetValues("X-Error"))[0]
```

Comment: I'm curious for the reason on the down vote on this Nisse. I included it here as its from a console app I'm using.

Comment: I downvoted this too because it's unsafe: The specification for `HttpHeaders` does not guarantee that `.GetValues(String)` will return a `String[]` (it only says it returns an `IEnumerable<String>`), and if there are no values for the specified name then you'll get an `InvalidOperationException` - and if the same header is repeated then this will only return the first value for the specified header name.

Comment: Another reason to downvote this answer is because the OP asked how to get "all headers" but this answer only returns the value of a single named header - so this doesn't answer the original question at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is for a request, but a response also got the same structure for Headers.
Tested in .net 6

```
somerequest.Headers.Select(x => new { x.Key, Value = x.Value?.FirstOrDefault() } )
```

This shows up in immediate windows as:

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>, <>f__AnonymousType0<string, string>>}
    [0]: {{ Key = Transfer-Encoding, Value = chunked }}
    [1]: {{ Key = Server, Value = Microsoft-IIS/10.0 }}
    [2]: {{ Key = WWW-Authenticate, Value = Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token expired at '03/29/2023 11:37:34'" }}
    [3]: {{ Key = X-Powered-By, Value = ASP.NET }}
    [4]: {{ Key = Date, Value = Thu, 30 Mar 2023 10:23:47 GMT }}
```

It resembles the question example of output. So you could then join the strings afterwards if you want to show this as a string for a log or output.