# HttpClient does not return Content-Type

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm sending a request with `HttpClient`. Server returns two headers which I want  return to client. I run it like this:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
     var response = await client.GetAsync(DownloadUri + $"?path={path}&fileName={fileName}");
     // ...
 }
```

But on client side I have 10 headers, while server sends 12. 
This is what I get in debugger for `response.Headers.ToString()`:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcQWxleFxEb2N1bWVudHNcdGZzXFVDRktcdnNuXGRldlxMYW5pdC5VQ0ZLLkZpbGUuU2VydmVyXEZpbGUuc3ZjXERvd25sb2Fk?=
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Cache-Control: private
Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2016 12:19:09 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

And this is what I get with external Rest client:
[image]

`Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` are missing.
How can I get it with `HttpClient`?

Comment: You arent sending any Accept-Headers, so there probably wont be a zipped (but raw) response and therefore no specified contenttype.

Comment: Correct duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/41836921/477420

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should look at `response.Content.Headers` you should find headers relating to the content here. More information about all the content header types can be found on the msdn link below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Content_type is part of the Content Headers. So you should use:

```
response.Content.Headers;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
  String sContentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
  Console.WriteLine($"Response ContentType: {sContentType}");
  //
  // Response ContentType: application/json
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it is different/better from other answers here.

Comment: It is a full example of the specific C# code to return the ContentType as a String, It show an example, (in the comment line) of what is output when the code is executed.Thus you do not have to further research the topic if this is all you need. The other answers just point you towards the answer. The code is, I believe, trivial to understand for anyone with some familiarity with C# and the topic in question.