# Get header response using httpclient vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I really new in this vb.net programing, still need lot of learning, heed some help here, so I try to use HTTPCLIENT to get data from website and the result is json, I'm able to get the body using this code

```
Dim node As String
Dim client As New HttpClient
Dim getStringTask As Task(Of String) = client.GetStringAsync("urltarget")
node = Await getStringTask
textbox1.text = node
```

I can display the json file in textbox1, but my question is how I can get the header response on textbox2 since the node result only contain the body

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpClient retrieve all headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320738/httpclient-retrieve-all-headers)

Comment: can u help me how to implement to my code above? I dont know how to convert the c# to vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling GetStringAsync() only returns a simple string.  Try this to get access to the whole response:

```
Dim client As New HttpClient
Dim response = Await client.GetAsync(url)
TextBox1.Text = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
TextBox2.Text = response.Headers.ToString()
```